# Play 2.1.2 unable to resolve javax.validation-1.0.0.GA

Tags: playframework, sbt, playframework-2.1

In my newly created play project, when i run `play eclipse` I get the following error:

```
sbt.ResolveException: download failed: javax.validation#validation-api;1.0.0.GA!validation-api.jar
```

If I run `sbt compile` in the same directory I get a `[success]` message

In both cases the sbt version is 0.12.2 (according to project/build.properties and sbt output)

If i `locate javax.validation` I find it in two locations:
`/opt/play-2.1.2/repository/local/javax.validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/jars/validation-api.jar` and `/home/wonko/.ivy2/cache/javax.validation/validation-api/jars/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar`

Why can't Play Framework find the dependency?

Comment: Are you working behind the firewall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to find the jar in the play directory [path]/play-2.1.1/repository
and delete the jar from local and cache then try again

Comment: I deleted every instance of javax.validation on my computer for good measure and it worked. Occurrencies where where you described and in ~/.ivy and ~/.m2
Thanks for your help!